# Meteor Scope error when using Autoform

Tags: meteor

Using autoform and dependencies plus iron router. Autopublish is on and I'm seeing the collection on the client console. New project on .8, everything newly installed.

in schema.js, which I've tried in a few locations (/lib, /)

```
Tvseries = new Meteor.Collection("tvseries", {
schema: {
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Title",
        max: 250
    },
    airStartDate: {
        type: Date,
        label: "First episode air date" 
    }
}
```

});

Then a very basic autoform taken from the example:

```
<template name="addseries">
    {{> quickForm collection="tvseries" id="inserttvseriesForm" type="insert"}}
</template>
```

Plus a route that is just loading this form:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('addseries', {
    path: '/addseries', 
    template: "addseries"

    });
});
```

I get this message in the JS console:

```
Exception from Deps recompute function: Error: tvseries is not in the window scope.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
<template name="addseries">
    {{> quickForm collection="Tvseries" id="inserttvseriesForm" type="insert"}}
</template>
```

Your collection is named as `Tvseries`, not `tvseries`.

Answer (score 1):

In case Serkan's typo suggestion didn't work, and for anyone looking for relief on this since this shows up on google and is how I got here:

From the [docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#should-the-value-of-schema-and-collection-have-quotation-marks-around-it) (this section is buried too far down IMO)

> Should the value of `schema` and `collection` have quotation marks around it?
>
> If you use quotation marks, then you are telling the autoform to "look for an object in the window scope with this name". So if you define your collections at the top level of your client files and without the var keyword, then you can use this trick to avoid writing helpers.
>
> If you don't use quotation marks, then you must define a helper function with that name and have it return the SimpleSchema or Mongo.Collection instance.

So you'd need a helper function that would look like this:

```
Template.addseries.helpers({
  Tvseries: function () {
    Return Tvseries;
  }
});
```

And if you have a schema that is not attached to the collection, you'd also create another helper to return the schema so that you can call it from the template. The docs recommend registering this helper globally:

```
Template.registerHelper('Schemas', Schemas);
```